# Battery replacment

Tags: voltage, batteries, connector, pins

I have a question about tablet battery. I have a Vodafone Tab prime 7 which needs a battery replacement and i figured out that i need Alcatel battery TLP058B2. The problem is this battery is discontinued long time ago and its rarely to find in china which is hard for me to get. Im thinking to connect a different battery with same voltages but the problem is im sooo noob about the connectors types and colors so im totally lost. Can someone help me please ?

[image]

Here is an image of the Alcatel battery connection with the color order. Thank you so much in advance guys and an idea will be much appreciated !

Comment: Hard to tell with the single blurry pic and no scale but it could be a Molex EZmate.  Expensive crimper and really fiddly to get right.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering. The model of the battery its in the question and i just screenshot the connector. you think there is a chance to use another battery?